# Using Reinforced Learning to create Artificial Neural Networks

Tags: java, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

Does anyone know how or can provide a way to find out how to use Reinforced Learning to create Artificial Neural Networks. In essence I am asking if anyone knows how to make a Neural Network that is able to adjust itself (or "learn") based on experience/ results to gain more reward (and if possible is willing to endure negative reinforcement to gain greater positive reinforcement). Additionally I am best at Java but I am wiling to learn new programming languages if necessary.

P.S. I know this questions is not what this platform has been designed to answer but I am desperate for an answer and personally believe the website's policies have been restricting community involvement and overall learning.

Comment: You will probably get shut down, but in the mean time I think you have to describe your problem - what kind of stimuli do you have, how many categories?

Comment: also supervised or unsupervised

Comment: Sorry, but have you tried googling for the answer? There is a ton of information on this subject.

Comment: maybe these can help you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.ai.neural-nets,  https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-deep-learning-and-usual-machine-learning,  https://www.neuron.yale.edu/phpBB/ - also maybe you can say if you have some software you'd prefer to use (e.g. Matlab or python)

Comment: unsupervised and yes I have googled it and one came up with articles about google and patents

Comment: this specifically is to be used for creating a neural network to explore in no man's sky and it stimuli is the in game currency

Comment: eep. Thats a big ask

Comment: Coursera has a machine learning course from stanford that goes into machine vision and all the various components you'll need, its free and very good, assuming your maths is up to scratch (mine wasn't, I choked out on the calculus stuff fairly early on). I'm afraid a stack overflow Q&A is unlikely to go anywhere near the level of detail you'll need to pull it off.

Comment: If you can write your own code based on translations of the underlying equations, I can point you to some resources that have the formulas for several variants of Reinforcement Learning.

Comment: The modern approach is using something called *Deep Reinforcement Learning* (in this case: Q-learning with NN as function-approximator) like used in [this](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/docs/dqn.pdf) very popular paper. The problem though is: your use-case sounds, like your Q-learning algorithm can only learn in real-time speed of the game. That's too slow!

Comment: And just one more small remark on the feasibility of your problem: the mentioned paper in my other comment was kind of a breakthrough (learning to play simple games only through pixel-observation). It took top-scientists a lot of work! Motivated by this success, there are a lot of platforms emerging, which prepare slightly more complex games like doom to be tackled by these ideas (splitting game and rl-algorithms). I don't think there is much success yet and these games are arguably much simpler than yours.I would expect,that a team of good researchers would also need years to solver your prob